# Will the LD3985 will turn on in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, ldo

This is a beginner's question.

In the LD3985 datasheet I found this example:

[image]

I made this circuit:

[image]

If i put a capacitor between INH pin and GND, will it run correctly or should I remove this capacitor?

Comment: That C is just in parallel with a much bigger one. It doesn't matter either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacitor is between VCC and GND. INH is connected to VCC. That will work as expected.